# Cannot log into Tor

Tags: network-configuration

The browser is saying, "tor failed to establish a tor network connection. 
"Starting failed (no route to host - 66.206.0.82:9001)

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Can you get to the internet using a regular browser? 2. Are you in a location where Tor might be blocked such as an office, a university, or in a country where it is not allowed?

Comment: Honestly, I had this happen and building a new circuit made it work. Have you made a new circuit?